# Javascript ternary operator: What is the condition in "(myvar) ?" when it is a number?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple Javascript question: What does the following line test on myvar ?

```
counter = (myvar) ? Math.ceil(counter/myvar) : Math.ceil(counter);
```

I understand that it is to prevent a division by zero. I googled ternary operators in Javascript, but all I could find were conditions with a comparator (like >, <, etc.)

If it translates to

```
if(myVar)
```

what does it test ?

Comment: When downvoting, at least have the decency to justifiy it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it translates to `if(myVar)` and means `if(0)`

> 0 means `false` and 
>   1 means `true`

In your case,

Non-zero: `counter = Math.ceil(counter/myvar);`

Zero: `counter = Math.ceil(counter);`

> Note:  `NaN`,`null`,`undefined`, +0 , -0 and `""` are all `false` too.

Answer (score 4):

> In [**`Conditional (ternary) Operator`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), If an expression is evaluated as `true`, value of `Expression 1` is returned or *otherwise.*

- [**`Truthy`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)
- [**`Falsy`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

---

#### `Falsy` Values

- `false`
- `(+/-)0` (zero)
- `""` (empty string)
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN` (a special Number value meaning Not-a-Number!)

***Note:*** *All other values are `truthy`, including "0" (zero in quotes), "false" (false in quotes), empty functions, empty arrays, and empty objects.[[Ref](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)]*

---

> `counter = (myvar) ? Math.ceil(counter/myvar) : Math.ceil(counter);`

In your case, If `myvar` is `truthy` value then `first-expression` else `second-expression`

Comment: I get that. But what is truthy for an integer ?

Comment: @Tim 0 is the only falsy integer

Comment: @le_m, How `sign(+/-)` make any difference ?

Answer (score 0):

It checks for `myvar` to be 0.

It translates

```
if (myvar === 0)
   counter = Math.ceil(counter);
else
   Math.ceil(counter/myvar)
```